# Django creates new user every time doing sign in with apple

Tags: python, ios, django, sign-in-with-apple

I implemented sign in with apple backend on Django by looking this repository's code: https://github.com/truffls/sign-in-with-apple-using-django/blob/master/backend.md.

I made very little changes to the code which should not affect to any logic(like changing declaration name and etc.)

It strangely re creates a new user every time an iOS app signs in with sign in with apple.

I there any way to fix this?

```
class AppleOAuth2(BaseOAuth2):
    """
    Custom BaseOAuth2 backend class for
    Sign in with Apple

    Usage:
    Add this to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS on settings.py
    """

    name             = 'apple'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token'
    SCOPE_SEPARATOR  = ','
    ID_KEY           = 'uid'

    @handle_http_errors
    def do_auth(self, access_token, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Finish the auth process once the access_token was retrieved
        Get the email from ID token received from apple

        do_auth override this method as you need to verify the code or access token given
        by mobile client from apple and get the ID token from which other details can be extracted.
        """

        ## Retrieve django project stored data
        client_id, client_secret = self.get_key_and_secret()

        headers = {'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        data = {
            'client_id'    : client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'code'         : access_token,
            'grant_type'   : 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' : 'https://example-app.com/redirect'
        }



        ## Form data

        # ID Token(= from AppleID Service)
        res = requests.post(AppleOAuth2.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, data = data, headers = headers)
        response_dict = res.json()
        id_token = response_dict.get('id_token', None)


        # Response Data
        response_data = {}

        if id_token:
            decoded = jwt.decode(id_token, '', verify = False)
            response_data.update({'email': decoded['email']}) if 'email' in decoded else None
            response_data.update({'uid': decoded['sub']}) if 'sub' in decoded else None

        # Response
        response = kwargs.get('response') or {}
        response.update(response_data)
        response.update({'access_token': access_token}) if 'access_token' not in response else None



        ## Authenticate
        kwargs.update({'response': response, 'backend': self})
        return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_user_details(self, response):
        """
        get_user_details override just to give the email address or other user
        information back to the Python Social Auth framework
        """
        email = response.get('email', None)
        details = {
            'email': email,
        }
        return details


    def get_key_and_secret(self):
        """
        get_key_and_secret override this as you have to generate
        the client secret the way mentioned above

        :return:
        - App Bundle ID
        - Client Secret
        """
        headers = {
            'kid': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_KEY_ID
        }

        payload = {
            'iss': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_TEAM_ID,
            'iat': timezone.now(),
            'exp': timezone.now() + timedelta(days = 180),
            'aud': 'https://appleid.apple.com',
            'sub': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_APP_BUNDLE_ID,
        }

        client_secret = jwt.encode(
            payload,
            settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_KEY_SECRET,
            algorithm = 'ES256',
            headers = headers
        ).decode("utf-8")

        return settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_APP_BUNDLE_ID, client_secret
```

I get error from Apple

```
{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'The code has expired or has been revoked.'}
```

Comment: It seems id_token is None thus uid is also None

Comment: I'm getting error response from https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, i solved by making few changes in this code,

we get two things from apple on client side after the authentication process complete one is **id_token** and other one is **code** and we are using id_token in our backend as a access_token which wrong, you have to use **code** as a access_token in backend side like below.

```
access_token = request.data['response_code'] # this response_code should coming from client side as i mention above you have to send `code` not `id_token` and use this as a access_token
```